how to get v2 type token using msal python
I am trying to get a v2 type token using the msal library for python
my code is as in below
global_app = msal.ClientApplication(
    os.getenv('CLIENT_ID'),
    authority=os.getenv('AUTHORITY'),  # For Entra ID or External ID
    oidc_authority=os.getenv('OIDC_AUTHORITY'),  # For External ID with custom domain
    client_credential=os.getenv('CLIENT_SECRET') or None,  # Treat empty string as None
    token_cache=global_token_cache,  # Let this app (re)use an existing token cache.
        # If absent, ClientApplication will create its own empty token cache
    )

result = global_app.acquire_token_by_username_password(
            os.getenv("USERNAME"), password, scopes=scopes)

Additionally i have tried to set and unset the scopes as User.Read.
I have also set the accesstokentype in the Azure manifests to v2.
However when i run the above, i still get the token with issuer as https://sts.... which is different from my issue which is of the type https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT}
I need assistance in getting the correct v2 token back

Note that, User.Read is Microsoft Graph permission for which version 2.0 tokens are not yet supported. Refer this MS Q&A by Sivakumar-MSFT.
I registered one application and set accessTokenAcceptedVersion in Azure Manifest to v2 as below:

When I decoded the token generated with User.Read scope, its version is 1.0 :

To get v2 type token, you need to create new custom scope by exposing an API like this:

Make sure to add this custom scope in API permissions tab and grant admin consent to it as below:

Now, generate the token by changing scope parameter to custom scope value  in your python code:
import msal
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()

client_id = os.getenv('CLIENT_ID')
authority = os.getenv('AUTHORITY')
oidc_authority = os.getenv('OIDC_AUTHORITY')
client_secret = os.getenv('CLIENT_SECRET') or None
username = os.getenv("USERNAME")
password = os.getenv("PASSWORD")
scopes = ["api://appId/custom.read"]

global_app = msal.ClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=client_secret,
    token_cache=None
)

result = global_app.acquire_token_by_username_password(
    username=username,
    password=password,
    scopes=scopes
)

if "access_token" in result:
    print("Access token:", result["access_token"])
else:
    print("Failed to acquire token.")
    print(result.get("error"))
    print(result.get("error_description"))

Response:

To confirm that, I decoded the token in jwt.ms website where token generated with version 2.0 successfully as below:

